# Encriptar RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding en vba?

Tags: excel, vba, rsa

Alguien cuenta o conoce cómo poder realizar la encripción en algoritmo RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding en vba para excel o cuenta con un ejemplo, he buscado y no he encontrado algo relacionado.

Estoy intentando encriptar una secuencia de numeros con el algoritmo RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding, no sé como agregar la llave, lo que he intentado genera error y no encuentro documentación relacionada con este proceso

Estoy utilizano hasta ahora:

```
    Function RSAEncryption(ByVal text As String, ByVal llave As String) As String
     Dim textoBytes() As Byte
     Dim bytes
     Dim outText As String
    
     Set codificador = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
     Set encript = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider")
     privateKey = encript.ExportParameters(True)
     publicKey = encript.ExportParameters(False)
    
     textoBytes = codificador.GetBytes_4(text)
     encript.ExportParameters (False)
     bytes = encript.Encrypt(textoBytes, False)
     'Convert the byte array to a hex string
     For pos = 1 To LenB(bytes)
         'outstr = outstr & LCase(Right("0" & Hex(AscB(MidB(bytes, pos, 1))), 2))
         outstr = outstr & LCase(Right("0" & Hex(AscB(MidB(bytes, pos, 1))), 2))
     Next
     FileToRSAHex = bytes
     'Set enc = Nothing
     RSAEncryption = FileToRSAHex
End Function
```

Pero no he podido dar con la ejecución adecuada.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Prueba dando contexto a la pregunta, dónde intentas hacerlo y si has intentado alguna cosa. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: *lo que he intentado genera error * ¿Qué linea? ¿Qué error? ¿Cuál es el output esperado? ¿para qué es el parámetro `llave` si luego no lo usas en el código? ¿Para qué el bucle si el resultado de `outstr` no lo usas tampoco?